# Multiple WebRequests all require authentication. How can i use keep alive to download all files througj one stream and only authenticate once?

Tags: c#

I need to download multiple files from a server. Each uri needs to be authenticated at the moment but this is killing server performance. I want to only authenticate one time and download all files that I stored in a list. I'm thinking using the keep alive but not sure how to implement. My code is:

```
foreach (var line in urls)
{
var content = new MemoryStream();
var webRequest =             
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(line);
webRequest.Credentials = new 
NetworkCredential("username", "password");
webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = 
DecompressionMethods.Deflate | 
DecompressionMethods.Gzip;
webRequest.proxy = null;
using(WebResponse resp = webRequest.GetResponse()
{
    using(Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponse())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(content);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, content.ToArray());
    }
    content.Dispose();
    resp.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: How the authentication is implemented? Is it http basic? What server "performance" are you trying to optimise?

Comment: Trying to simulate many users accessing server at same time to see how it performs. The authentication for each file is making the CPU spike when users try to access files. It is Http basic.

Comment: So how about optimising an authentication process instead? Checking a username and a password should not be a resource intensive process.